Would the Borg react to an escape pod?
I know the Borg assimilate whatever they encounter and only engage in activate combat if they are attacked or the collective decides they pose too great a risk.
But escape pods are at the very least unarmed or at best poorly armed. I don't even think escape pods have shields.
So I'm wondering "Would the Borg react to an escape pod?" and if they would "What would their reaction be." I know it can be argued that they would assimilate everyone on the escape pod and possibly the escape pod itself.

Where does 'the Borg… only engage in active combat if… attacked' come from, please? Isn't 'active combat' the Borg's normal means of assimilation? Isn't it their sole strategy?

I suggest it's not about whether an escape pod poses a threat, but solely how efficient it might be to assimilate the passengers. Who cares about the material in the pod itself?
What threat does a pod pose, but raising the alarm? Why would the Borg mind that, even if pod-speed didn't mean that alarm would take a long time to change anything?
More…

Further… I forget which film - possibly Logan's Run; perhaps THX 1138 - showed some truly scary lawmen inexorably, irresistibly closing in on their target… until Head Office bean counter called them off.
That the Good Guys were hardly six feet away from the Blokes in Black counted for nothing. Having run up against its budget, the search project was automatically suspended with no appeal proocedure.

The Borg have the same sort of goal-orientation you'd expect to see in a toddler; going after the things they want with monomaniacal obsession but treating anything that doesn't interest them as being of no importance whatsoever.
If they're after a biological sample, then jumping into a slow-moving escape pod would just make you an easy-to-grab target.
On the other hand, if they're on their way to a bigger prize and you're trying to stop them, they'll destroy you, if you pose a threat, or ignore you if you don't. That being the case, getting into an escape pod would absolutely work, but so also would just not attacking them in the first place.

Ben Sisko escapes from the Borg (at 'The Battle of Wolf-359') in an escape pod in DS9: The Emissary. They leave him alone.



